# Evaluating $\int_0^{2 \pi} (A+\cos(x))^c (A-\cos(x))^{-c} d x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anybody help me with the values of the following integrals

$\int\limits_0^{2 \pi} (A+\cos(x))^c (A-\cos(x))^{-c} d x$

and more general this integral

$\int\limits_0^{2 \pi} (A+\cos(x))^c (A-\cos(x))^{-c} |\sin(x)|^s d x.$

Here $A \geq 0$, $c$ non-negative, and $s$ complex. A reference to a table with integrals will also be okay.

Thanks.

Comment: If $|A|<1$ and $c\geq 1$ the integrals do not converge!

Comment: integrals in the title and body of the post are not the same. which expressions are raised to the power $c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the table will be of much help, but perhaps the following steps could get the ball rolling:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(A+\cos x\right)^{c}}{\left(A-\cos x\right)^{c}}dx=
 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(2A+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^{c}}{\left(2A-e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)^{c}}dx$$
$$e^{ix}=z$$
$$ie^{ix}dx=dz$$
$$dx=-i\frac{dz}{z}$$
$$I=-i\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{z^{2}+2A+1}{-z^{2}+2Az-1}\right)^{c}dz$$

Roots of the denominator in brackets
$$z^{2}-2Az+1=0$$
$$z_{1,2}=A\pm\sqrt{A^{2}-1}$$
So residues at these points and the rigid need to be examined. However for $c<0$ you need to keep track of the branches so the keyhole-style contour may be required